# Page Animation - Scrolling Text

Tags: php, javascript, html, scroll

I want to create a effect similar to the following site link, where the text is displayed in a fix sized text box that is then scrollable, however I want to use similar graphical design style as in example as opposed to using standard HTML scroll bar for it.

I also want the page never to need be refreshed, e.g. when you click on a different menu heading it just changes the content displayed, and does not have to reload the page. I know this part can be done with Javascript, and have a fair idea of how to go about it, but have no idea where to start on first part.

The example site uses Flash for all it's animation. However I want to stick to sever/client side languages, e.g. HTML/HTML5, Javascript/jquery, PHP

Example site:

http://www.theoceancollective.com/main.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good start for animations, Ajax and Javascript is to use a library like [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com). You can still use the menu with real url's which go to the right url for SEO reasons. But when a user presses that button, Javascript will cancel the real request and use an Ajax call to get the content. Small example using jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $("#menu li a").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); // Cancel the page change
        var _this = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url : "/urltogetpagecontent.php",
            success : function(result)
            {
                // Put result in #content div
                $("#content").html(result);
                // Change page selected, the new LI will have the class selected and it will be removed from the other LI's within #menu
                _this.parent().addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected")
            }
        });
    });
});
```

This way you can still use the original Navigation but cancel the pagechange. This will be called on document ready and will be bound to the `click` event of the `#menu li a`. If you want to have content with a fixed height, you can put your CSS as the `#content` as follow:

```
#content
{
    height: 600px;
    overflow: auto; /* Makes scrollbar when needed */
}
```

If you want to slide in and slide out your content. You have to got a DIV surrounded which will be added to you `#content`. So the structure will be something like:

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="page">
        // Default page
    </div>
    <div class="page">
        // Second page loaded
    </div>
</div>
```

And the success function will look something like:

```
success : function(result)
        {
            // Put result in #content div
            var result = $(result).hide();
            $("#content").append(result);
            $("#content page").slideUp(); // Slide old content up
            result.stop(true, false).slideDown(); // Slide new content down

            // Change page selected, the new LI will have the class selected and it will be removed from the other LI's within #menu
            _this.parent().addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected")
        }
```

Above example uses (some read stuff):

1. [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/)
2. [jQuery.siblings](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)
3. [jQuery.addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) / [jQuery.removeClass](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)
4. [jQuery.slideDown](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/) / [jQuery.slideUp](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/)

Possible improvements:
This code does not use any caching, sow when you click a link a second time, it does another Ajax request. You can improve this by giving the `.page` classes an ID which is linked to a `#menu li a`.

Answer (score 1):

1. you can use div to keep all your text content and give fixed height and overflow:auto in your style, you will get scroll automatically according to your text content height and use some script to apply / make fancy scroll bar.
2. Jquery is the best option to bring your content without loading/refresh the page. Each click of your header link use Jquery.load to load your other page content and load in main body/div  content